# Passing a global variable between functions

Tags: javascript

I'm having a bit of an issue with passing a global variable value between functions...my `cssStr` always contains `indo` with a value of `1` no matter what I set the value to using the `setindo()` function. The debug alert inside that function is always correct.

```
var indo = "1";

function setindo(passedvalue) {
    indo = passedvalue;
    alert("indo = " + indo);
}


$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){


var cssStr = ".upload-preview" + indo + " img";
var preview = $(cssStr);

$(".file").change(function (event) {            //file is the class id
    var input = $(event.currentTarget);
    var file = input[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //var title1 = $('#file').attr('id');
    alert("indo = " + indo);
    alert(cssStr);
    reader.onload = function(e){
        image_base64 = e.target.result;
        preview.attr("src", image_base64);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to pass global variables between functions.  They are global to all functions that need them.

Comment: I shouldn't have phrased it the way I did.. getting late now a bit tired haha. When the global variable `indo` is called when setting the `cssStr` variable it's value is always the default. However when I use a debug alert after setting the value, its correct.

Comment: Passing a number type variable to a function will be pass by value, rather than pass by reference, which means the value will be assigned to a local variable that only has scope inside the function. Changing it won't change the value globally.

Comment: Where are you calling `setindo()` and what are you passing it?  We need to see that code.

Comment: *setIndo* is never called and there is no other assignment to *indo*, so why do you expect the value change?

Comment: `<input id="img1" class="file" type="file" onClick="setindo('1');">`

Comment: Your string `cssStr` is created _once_ with the first value of `indo`. Is that what you want?

Comment: I've now directly set my `cssStr` variable inside `setIndo()` instead of in the `ready()` function. Similar story really, whenever the `ready()` is called `cssStr` reverts back to its default value. `cssStr` is now also declared globally.

Comment: elclanrs - that is what is happening, but not what I want to happen. I need to create `cssStr` with the NEW value of `indo` as set in the function `setIndo`

Comment: Got it! had to remove the `preview` variable from the function and make that global also... thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is that `cssStr` is defined once, when the document first loads. The variable's value does not change when `indo`'s value does — they are not related at all after the string has been created. If you want to use the value of `indo` when that function is called, then construct the `cssStr` within that function rather than when the document loads.

Comment: Thanks! I made `cssStr` and `preview` both global and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Within `setindo`, use the value of `cssStr` instead and then it will truly be global.  Currently `passedvalue` is in the local scope to `setindo`

Comment: `var cssStr = null;

    function setindo(passedvalue){
 cssStr = ".upload-preview" + passedvalue + " img";
 alert(cssStr);
 }`

Comment: ? *cssStr* is local to the function expression passed to *ready*. The *setindo* function can't access it.

Comment: I have now done this, but its just doesn't seem to working correctly